# rsyslog write $programname as kafka topic

Tags: apache-kafka, rsyslog

I want to write messages from `rsyslog` to kafka, use `rsyslog $programname` or `$syslogtag` as topic, however, omkafaka plugin didn't accept params, how can I achieve this?

I have tried using `(type="omkafka" topic="$programname" ...)`, it fails.

Comment: I solved this by myself, omkafka 8.xx have a new property to accept dynamic topic. But thanks any way.

Comment: you can put the solution that worked in the answer box and accept it yourself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this by myself, omkafka 8.xx have a new property to accept dynamic topic, just config the property and add a template to inject dynamic topic.

```
template(name="kafka_topic" type="string" string="%programname%")
input(type="imtcp" port="10514")
action(type="omkafka" topic="kafka_topic" dynatopic="on" dynatopic.cachesize="1000" template="msg_template" broker=["xxx", "xxx", "xxx", "xxx"])
```